# Prove that $SL(2,R)$ is a subgroup of $GL(2,R)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, solution-verification

Let $SL(2,R)=[A \in GL(2,R); det(A)=1]$. Prove that $SL(2,R)$ is a subgroup of $GL(2,R)$.

Here is what I have using subgroup criteria but I'm not sure if this proof is right.
Proof: Clearly $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}=I_{2} \in SL(2,R)$. Thus, $SL(2,R)$ is nonempty.
I) Closure: Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\in SL(2,R)$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}a'&b'\\c'&d'\end{bmatrix}\in SL(2,R)$. Also, $\det(AB)=det(A)*det(B)=1*1=1$. So $AB\in SL(2,R)$.
II) Inverses: Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\in SL(2,R)$. Then, $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{det(A)}*\begin{bmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{bmatrix}\in SL(2,R), d\et(A^{-1})=det(A)^{-1}=1^{-1}=1$. Thus, $A^{-1}\in SL(2,R)$. Thus, $SL(2,R)$ is a subgroup of $GL(2,R)$.

Comment: Its the kernel of the determinant map. And that is basically your argument.

Comment: the proof is completely correct.

Comment: You already know that $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ is a group; therefore, you just need to show that $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})\subseteq\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and that multiplication in both groups is the same when restricted to $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have verified only three axioms of 4 axioms of a group. The last one is that the group operation, say $*$, is also associative, i.e. $A*(B*C)=(A*B)*C$ for all elements $A,B,C$. Here the elements of group are matrices, so the group operation is matrix multiplication. The associativity is automatically satisfied for matrix multiplication.

Comment: I think this is unnecessary. The presumption of the question is that $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is a group (which is true), and the question asks to prove that $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup. To do that, it is necessary and sufficient to check that the subset satisfies the three axioms that were already checked by the OP. It is unnecessary to re-check the associativity axiom, because that axiom is already satisfied for all triples of elements in the group $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: You're right. I just wanted to remind that in general 4 axioms should be verified and finally mentioned it is automatically satisfied in this case.

Comment: Also, for this topic in the class, we're going by 2 criteria for subgroups: 1) closure and 2) inverses. For groups in general, we used all 4 axioms.